# Can We multiply a constant in a proportionality?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

If we have a proportionality stating y is proportional to x can we say y is proportional to maybe 2x or kx in general?
Because if y is proportional to x and x in turn is a function say 5z then y is proportional to 5z.
But the problem arises if we put in the constant term to be 0, then a variable is proportional to a constant.
I understand that this is a radical though but it hit me while doing physics but I thought it is more of a Math problem

Comment: What is the definition of being proportional?  $y$ is proportional to $x$ iff there exists some $k$ such that $y=kx$?  If that is the case, then ask if $y$ is proportional to $\alpha x$ (with $\alpha\neq 0$).  The answer being yes since $y=kx=\frac{k}{\alpha}(\alpha x)$.

Comment: I agree but what is to stop us from saying that maybe α is 0, which makes a variable proportional to a constant which cannot be true

Comment: @PrabhdeepSingh $\alpha$ must be non-zero by definition

Comment: and why is that?

Comment: @PrabhdeepSingh Read JMoravitz's comment carefully.  When we define "$y$ is proportional to $x$" we EXPLICITLY  ASSUME $\alpha$ is not $0$

Comment: @PrabhdeepSingh If $\alpha = 0$ we cannot simplify $\frac{k}{\alpha}(\alpha x)$ to $kx$ because division by $0$ is not defined.

Comment: Thanks I got it now, moreover 2 things are said to be proportional when their ratio is a constant that implies y/x must be a constant and infinity into 0 is not a constant. Thanks for the help